# fails installing node package using npm on debian

Tags: linux, node.js, debian, npm

I have just built a server and installed NodeJS (compiled from source). I can install global packages using npm but can't install anything locally:

```
$ npm install restify
npm ERR! Error: Attempt to unlock restify@~2.6.2, which hasn't been locked
npm ERR!     at unlock (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/cache.js:1304:11)
npm ERR!     at cb (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/cache.js:646:5)
npm ERR!     at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/cache.js:655:20
npm ERR!     at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/cache.js:1290:7
npm ERR!     at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/lockfile/lockfile.js:167:38
npm ERR!     at OpenReq.Req.done (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/graceful-fs/graceful-fs.js:144:5)
npm ERR!     at OpenReq.done (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/graceful-fs/graceful-fs.js:64:22)
npm ERR!     at Object.oncomplete (fs.js:107:15)
npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this *entire* log,
npm ERR! including the npm and node versions, at:
npm ERR!     <http://github.com/npm/npm/issues>

npm ERR! System Linux 3.5.0-23-generic
npm ERR! command "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "install" "restify"
npm ERR! cwd /home/likewise-open/COVENTRY/aa7401/bookshop
npm ERR! node -v v0.10.26
npm ERR! npm -v 1.4.3
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Additional logging details can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/likewise-open/.../npm-debug.log
npm ERR! not ok code 0
$
```

I am running the current versions of node and npm:

```
$ node -v
v0.10.26
$ npm -v
1.4.3
$
```

I am having the same issues with the request package as well.
I am the owner of the folder and all the files int contains.
Does anyone know what is going on?

Answer (score 0):

The issue may be the permissions on the .npm directory in the home directory. I belatedly found this post:

[NPM cannot install dependencies - Attempt to unlock something which hasn't been locked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22152162/npm-cannot-install-dependencies-attempt-to-unlock-something-which-hasnt-been)

Unfortunately until I get into work tomorrow I have no way to confirm this.