# Installing gulp with npm

Tags: node.js, npm, digital-ocean

i am trying to install gulp via npm on DigitalOcean droplet with following command (with and without sudo):

```
npm install -g gulp
```

and im getting errors i cant figure out:

```
> v8flags@1.0.5 install /root/local/lib/node_modules/gulp/node_modules/v8flags
> node fetch.js

sh: 1: node: Permission denied
npm ERR! Linux 3.13.0-24-generic
npm ERR! argv "node" "/root/local/bin/npm" "install" "-g" "gulp"
npm ERR! node v0.10.33
npm ERR! npm  v2.1.11
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE

npm ERR! v8flags@1.0.5 install: `node fetch.js`
npm ERR! Exit status 127
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the v8flags@1.0.5 install script 'node fetch.js'.
npm ERR! This is most likely a problem with the v8flags package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     node fetch.js
npm ERR! You can get their info via:
npm ERR!     npm owner ls v8flags
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     /root/local/bin/npm-debug.log
```

The node install is made according to [this](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-an-upstream-version-of-node-js-on-ubuntu-12-04) guide.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I had the same issue, installing an earlier version of gulp worked for me:

```
sudo npm install -g gulp@3.8.8
```

Found this here: http://forum.ionicframework.com/t/osx-error-v8flags-after-npm-update-ionic/13905/5

Also tried a bunch of other solutions involving solutions as mentioned here:
[NPM cannot install dependencies - Attempt to unlock something which hasn't been locked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22152162/npm-cannot-install-dependencies-attempt-to-unlock-something-which-hasnt-been)

None of that worked for me.

The error I was getting was this:

```
shell-init: error retrieving current directory: getcwd: cannot access parent directories: Permission denied
/
node.js:815
    var cwd = process.cwd();
                      ^
Error: EACCES, permission denied
    at Function.startup.resolveArgv0 (node.js:815:23)
    at startup (node.js:58:13)
    at node.js:906:3
```

Comment: You should post the example of the code, and not links because links cannot be guaranteed to be static.

Comment: Edited to highlight relevant code, the links are merely for reference.