# Phonegap installation fails using npm

Tags: macos, cordova, npm

I followed this [Up and running with PhoneGap on Mac OSX](http://www.panopticdev.com/blog2014/phonegap-mac-osx-setup-configuration-android-ios/) on every single step but then I got stuck with [image: error]

I have tried many solutions and fixes but still nothing is working. I followed [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22152162/npm-cannot-install-dependencies-attempt-to-unlock-something-which-hasnt-been) but still stuck.

What could be the cause for these issues?!

**Update1:**

When I install cordova using `sudo npm install -g cordova` I get the following:
[image: Install Cordova]

Even when I type cordova, I get `-bash: cordova: command not found`

**Update2:**

I fixed cordova installation using the following steps:

1. sudo chown -R $USER /usr/local
2. sudo chmod -R 0775 /usr/local
3. Add it to the path using [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9679932/how-to-use-package-installed-locally-in-node-modules)
4. Add the path to `bash_profile` using [this link](http://hathaway.cc/post/69201163472/how-to-edit-your-path-environment-variables-on-mac)

Open the terminal and type `cordova -v` and you get it working displaying the version

Phonegap is still failing and can't seem to find a fix for it

Comment: what does happen when you run `sudo npm install -g cordova`?

Comment: @Sithys I have updated the question with that part.

Comment: and who should read that tiny text on that image?

Comment: @Sithys sorry about that. I updated the screenshot