# impossible to use npm as sudo with nvm

Tags: node.js, ubuntu, npm, sudo, nvm

I have install node/npm using the nvm documentation.

> curl -o- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/creationix/nvm/v0.26.1/install.sh | bash

I then install it:

> nvm install stable

and then I have to do:

> nvm use node

npm is working but if I want to install a package globally it doesn't work.

> sudo npm install -g package

I've got this:

> sudo: npm: command not found

I've seen many topic but I didn't really understand anything with symbolic link or something like this.
I'm using ubuntu 14.04

Answer (score 9):

`nvm` maintainer here - with http://nvm.sh, you should *never* need to use sudo.

Also, `nvm` is per-user - meaning, the `sudo` user won't have it in its shell environment, and its PATH won't be set up properly anyways.

Just do `npm install -g package` and it will work perfectly :-)

Also, if you do `nvm alias default node`, you won't have to `nvm use` every time you open up a new shell!

Comment: So if I don't have to use sudo how do i overcome this issue: Error: EACCES: permission denied when trying to access .npm in my home

Comment: You may have installed node/npm with sudo prior to using `nvm`. My recommendation is to sudo chown your entire home directory so that you own it, and uninstall the system version of node/npm.

Comment: @LJHarb npm start need admin privileges. but cannot run with sudo. what to do then?

Comment: @bazi Why would `npm start` ever need admin privileges? Perhaps https://thomashunter.name/blog/using-authbind-with-node-js/ would be helpful for you.

Comment: I need sudo specifically because `npm install -g package` isn’t solving my problem, and I need to `npm i package` in a particular directory.

Comment: then put a package.json there, and `npm install` will install it in that directory's node_modules.

If you're trying to set up a package in a way that's fighting node ecosystem conventions, you're going to have a bad time.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you install global packages as a normal user?

```
npm install -g package
```

Comment: because I have Error: EACCES: permission denied when trying to access .npm in my home

Comment: Because it was created earlier with sudo. try deleting the folder (just rename it) and then do the various `npm install -g package`

Answer (score -1):

I found the answer in this [topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22152162/npm-cannot-install-dependencies-attempt-to-unlock-something-which-hasnt-been).

It's because I install it using sudo. 
I have to do those command:

```
sudo chown -R $USER ~/.npm
sudo chown -R $USER /usr/local/lib/node_module
```

And now it's work

Comment: When using `nvm`, `/usr/local/lib/node_module` shouldn't be used either. Do you have a `prefix` set in `~/.npmrc`? if so, please remove it.